# how to use ICollection for SelectList in Contoller of MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing .NET MVC application.

I want to send the collection of the objects from controller to View using select list. 
**without using view bag.**

**ViewModel :**

```
    public class AdviceCreateVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AdviceNo { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CompanyVM> Companies { get; set; }
     }

    public class CompanyVM
    {
     public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller Code :**

```
public class AdviceCreateController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
   adviceVM.Companies = new SelectList(ledgerService.GetAll().OrderBy(t => t.Name), "Id", "Name");
    }
}
```

It gives an error -

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: does `Companies` property have to be `ICollection<CompanyVM>`? `SelectList` inherits from `MultiSelectList`, which implements `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. `ICollection` is an interface which inherits from `IEnumerable` (that's why "an explicit conversion exists").

Comment: No, I didnt mentioned the ICollection<CompanyVM> in CompanyVM, Is that necessary ?

Comment: here: `adviceVM.Companies = new SelectList(...);`, `adviceVM` is `AdviceCreateVM`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign a `SelectList` to property of type `ICollection<CompanyVM>` -- which won't work. You need some like:

```cs
var viewModel = new AdviceCreateVM
{
    adviceVM.Companies = 
        ledgerService.GetAll().OrderBy(t => t.Name)
                              .Select(t=>
                                  new CompanyVM
                                  {
                                      Id = t.Id,  // "Id"
                                      Name = t.Name // "Name"
                                  })
                              .ToList()
};
```

I'm just guessing on the assignments here, since you didn't specify them.

In the view, you will have to make the select list from  `Companies` property.

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyId, 
                      model.Companies.Select(company => 
                          new SelectListItem
                          { 
                              Value = company.Id, 
                              Text = company.Name
                          }), "--Select Company--")
```

Comment: I have tried, but it gives error like this... Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<epay.ViewModel.CompanyVM>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: The important thing here is the `.Select` LINQ method, which will project (or transform, if you prefer) the items into CompanyVM objects.

Comment: Its not giving error in controller but giving error in view...'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<epay.ViewModel.AdviceCreateVM>' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor' 
             and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>,
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>,
    string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CompanyId,Model.Companies,"--Select Company--")

Comment: added the method to transform the `CompanyVM` objects into `SelectListItem` objects.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, `SelectList` does not implement `ICollection`.  Change you view model collection to `SelectList`

```
public class AdviceCreateVM
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string AdviceNo { get; set; }
  public SelectList Companies { get; set; } // change to select list
  public int CompanyID { get; set; } // for binding the the drop down list
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    AdviceCreateVM model = new AdviceCreateVM(); // initialise model
    model.Companies = new SelectList(ledgerService.GetAll().OrderBy(t => t.Name), "Id", "Name");
}
```

View

```
@model YourAssembly.AdviceCreateVM

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  ....
  @Html.DropDownFor(m => m.CompanyID, Model.Companies)
  ...
```

Comment: Good, but complex way to do it

Comment: I cant use SelectList in the class...It should be isolate from .net framework/MVC...

Comment: I assumed that because you had `VM` in the name it was a view model (which is what view models are for)

Comment: I'm trying to understand your last comment (you question even referred to the model as a view model).  The whole purpose of a view model is to represent the information you want to display in the view and is typically used to add `DataAnnotations` for display and validation, `SelectList`'s for use in drop down lists and properties or collections of other information which may not be directly related to the model.  They typically reference `System.Component.DataAnnotations` and `System.Web.MVC`. Whats why you use a view model and not the model itself to display the data.

Comment: Yes, Its only used to display the data... tomorrow, if I pulled out these classes and used in any other other framework than Microsoft,then it should work...

Comment: It looks like view models that don't have a dependency on MVC is a requirement.

Comment: But the view model is specific to an application. Its the model that you should be able to reuse. And if you were to use that model in say a WPF application, it would have its own view model. This [article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/188/View-Model-Design-And-Use-In-Razor-Views) might help explain it better